# Receiving UDP messages in Python while reading data from 3 ADCs

Tags: python, loops, udp

Hi guys I'm new here and new to Python as well. I'm trying to get my Raspberry Pi to control the temperature of my jacuzzi while being able to manually and remotely (using UDP) override its "decisions". Basically I have 3 AD Converters sending data to my RPi via GPIO of the temperature of a solar heater, the amount of sun light, and Spa temp, which would automatically control the spa pump.
I have 2 pieces of code which work fine independently of each other:

I can read my ADCs every 30 seconds using this code:
(read_bottom_sensor and read_top_sensor are defined earlier in the code as a part of SPI bit-banging)

```
while True:
        bottom_sensor = read_bottom_sensor(bottom_sensor_adc, SPICLK, SPIMOSI, SPIMISO, SPICS)
        current_spa_temp = bottom_sensor
        if DEBUG:
                print "Spa Temp = ", current_spa_temp



        top_sensor = read_top_sensor(top_sensor_adc, SPICLK, SPIMOSI, SPIMISO, SPICS)
        current_solar_heater_temp = top_sensor
        if DEBUG:
                print "Solar Heater Temp = ", current_solar_heater_temp



        if bottom_sensor + 10 < top_sensor:
                GPIO.output(PUMPRLY, True)
                print "The Pump is ON"
        else:
                GPIO.output(PUMPRLY, False)
                print "The Pump is OFF"
        time.sleep(30)
```

I can also turn the pump relay (PUMPRLY) connected to GPIO pin #7 on/off through my cellphone via UDP using the following code:

```
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(64)

    if data == b'7H':
        GPIO.output(7, True)

    elif data == b'7L':
        GPIO.output(7, False)
```

So far so good. The problem is that when I combine the 2 together, the sampling of the ADCs stops and waits to receive any UDP and only then it continues down the code. i.e. my code stops at the point it sees the  "data, addr = sock.recvfrom(64)" statement.

Do I need some kind of version of multiple interrupts and how would i do this in order to get the ADC sampling to continue every 30 sec, while still being able to receive UDPs independently. I thought it should be as simple as this:

```
while True:
        bottom_sensor = read_bottom_sensor(bottom_sensor_adc, SPICLK, SPIMOSI, SPIMISO, SPICS)
        current_spa_temp = bottom_sensor
        if DEBUG:
                print "Spa Temp = ", current_spa_temp



        top_sensor = read_top_sensor(top_sensor_adc, SPICLK, SPIMOSI, SPIMISO, SPICS)
        current_solar_heater_temp = top_sensor
        if DEBUG:
                print "Solar Heater Temp = ", current_solar_heater_temp



        if bottom_sensor < top_sensor + 10:
                GPIO.output(PUMPRLY, True)
                print "The Pump is ON"
        else:
                GPIO.output(PUMPRLY, False)
                print "The Pump is OFF"


        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(64)

            if data == b'7H':
                GPIO.output(7, True)

            elif data == b'7L':
                GPIO.output(7, False)
        time.sleep(30)
```

But it didn't work.
FYI The timing of the UDP is not important. I don't mind if it waits 30 sec in order to execute a received UDP message, as long as it doesn't interrupt the sampling of the ADCs.
Keep in mind I'm very new to programming and I did not come up with the code above, I simply copied it and changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use select() in order to only read from ready sockets in the main() loop. Select() is a time-proven standard library function, and works properly on both Linux and Windows. http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew it's probably something people learn in Python 101 but after a few hours of research on "select()" (did I mention a suck at programming) I was able to come up with the following 2 lines of code which works perfect for my application:     ....ready = select.select([RxSock],[],[],3)
 if ready[0]:
  dataIn = RxSock.recvfrom(512)